# How can I find the subsequential limit, limit sup, and limit inf of $s_n=n\tan\frac{n\pi}{3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

$s_n=n\tan\frac{n\pi}{3}$

How can this sequence be decomposed to the the set of subsequences so that I can find the limit sup, and limit inf?

I suppose I could just take $n$ and then $\tan\frac{n\pi}{3}$, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: The tangent piece will repeat itself every three terms, so I would consider three different subsequences based on $n  (mod 3)$

Comment: @Merlin, $\{-\frac{\pi}{2}, 0, \frac{\pi}{2}\}$?

Comment: The tangent piece will take on the values $0$, $\sqrt{3}$,$-\sqrt{3}$, in that order, over and over, as per $Olivier's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
 s_n=n\tan\frac{n\pi}{3} =
    \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $n=3\pi k$} \\[2ex]
n\sqrt{3},  & \text{if $n=3\pi k+1$} \\[2ex]
-n\sqrt{3},  & \text{if $n=3\pi k+2$} .
\end{cases}
$$